# Compiling Quake 3 in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, quake3

First of all I have Xcode 4 installed in Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8. I have downloaded the Quake 3 source code 1.32b release but I can't open the Xcode project that is inside the /macosx folder since it is in the old .pbproj format and therefore it throws an "incompatible version" error. Has anyone been able to convert this to a Xcode format or is there any other way to compile the source code in Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this is related to gamedev actually. The question is about "How to open old XCode project in newer version?" and is more appropriate for StackOverflow really.

Comment: I suggest you do as Krom suggests and open a new question on StackOverflow, in a more generic form.

Answer (score 3):

The original Quake 3 source was released quite some time ago.  I wouldn't be surprised if it's out of date.

I would suggest the [ioquake3](http://ioquake3.org/) version, except that I tried it recently on Leopard and the build failed for me.  Your mileage may vary.

The ioquake there is essentially just bug fixes and maintenance work on top of the original quake3 source.  If you just want to study the engine or do some prototyping it should be a better starting point than the original source that id released.  Plus, it's in svn so you can get the history of changes if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

try adding .xcode to end of the folder name. open it in xcode and save it as an xcodeproj

Comment: This answer isn't very specific, could you provide more details?

Answer (score -1):

## Opening and browsing

To be able open project with latest XCode go through steps:

1. Download and install **Xcode 2.5 Developer Tools for
   Mac OS X v10.4 (Tiger) and Mac OS X v 10.5 (Leopard)** from [developers.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)
2. Open code/macosx/Quake3.pbproj in XCode 2.5 and it will prompt you to save `.xcodeproj` project file
3. Open project in XCode 4/5 and browse the project